# SQL Tautologies pattern is not clear

Tags: security, owasp

I have a question about rule id 942130 (https://github.com/fastly/waf_testbed/blob/master/templates/default/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf.erb). Why check this rule "only" x = x in this pattern (x can be any character). The attack can only be successful if there is an "or" in the query "or x=x". For this reason, the pattern should be expanded so that "or x = x" is checked. Have I overlooked something?

Example is: "FooH=HA", which is deteced as a sql injection, but don't understand why. The issue is the "H=H".

Shouldn't the pattern compare the whole string before and after = instead of just single characters?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot more complicated to describe the rule in a regex (which is already quite complicated). A lot of things could happen between OR and x=x that would still be syntactically valid.

Also OR is not actually needed. Consider for example sql injection where the parameter is meant to be something like "ORDER BY x", and the attacker passing "WHERE x=x". Or HAVING. Or a lot of other potential attacks.

It's just a lot simpler to define a tautology as x=x, which would not normally happen most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But this example should work "FooH=HA". But the rule/pattern decline this input text, because "H=H" match the pattern

What do you think?

Comment: Hey Gabor, In my view, the whole string should be compared before and after the = and not just a part. Because an input string FooH = HBar is not a true condition. I would expect that FooH=FooH is detected and not more